# pubsvn http url to svn url

Tags: svn

How would I import an pubsvn link with svn?

What is the corresponding svn link to this url:

https://cnlohr.net/pubsvn/mcclient/NonEuclid/

Answer (score 1):

That is a SVN URL.  I don't see anything special about it, he's just put pubsvn in the path.

So to check it out:

```
svn checkout https://cnlohr.net/pubsvn/mcclient/NonEuclid/
```

Now if by import you mean how would you import the code there into another SVN repository.  Then probably what you want to do is:

```
svn export https://cnlohr.net/pubsvn/mcclient/NonEuclid/
```

and then copy the files into your working copy or use svn import to import those files into your repository.  If you want to try and keep this data in sync with the repository you may want to look into vendor branches:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html